# Can we redo the tag 1099-b

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Can we redo the tag [1099-b](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1099-b).

Either create this as per standard tag [form-1099-b](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-1099-b) and a synonym as [1099-b](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1099-b)

OR

Make the tag [1099-b](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/1099-b) as synonym to one of the existing generic tag [form-1099](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/form-1099)

Comment: Happy to update it if people who know about it could determine whether to use form-1099 or form-1099-b.